# Is there any RSpec expectation for any instance of a given kind?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to cover my Ruby on Rails code with tests. I use RSpec for testing.

Is there any way how to mock calls on instances based on their kind? (`kind_of?`). I want to test if children of the given parent class get called. I'd expect something like `allow_any_kind_of` method, similar to `allow_any_instance_of`. However I'm not able to find anything like that.

Here is my code example.
I have `Base` class and a few its children. In test it does not matter what exact child is used.

```
class Parent
  def my_method; end
end
class ChildA < Parent; end
class ChildB < Parent; end

class App
  def apply  
    [ChildA.new, ChildB.new].all? { |c| c.my_method }
  end
end
```

My RSpec test. It fails because neither ChildA or ChildB are instances of Parent class. I can have multiple `allow_any_instance_of` to cover all `Parent`'s children but I'd like to keep it simple as there will be way more children in real code.

```
context "#apply" do
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(Parent).to receive(:my_method).and_return(true)
  end

  it "returns true" do
    expect(subject.apply).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no straight forward way to set expectations of any instance of sub-classes. however injecting the dependencies into your  method will make it easier for you to test it.

you could rewrite it in a way similar to the following:

```
class App
 def initialize(params_hash)
   @children = params_hash[:children] || [ChildA.new, ChildB.new]
 end

 def apply  
   children.all? { |c| c.my_method }
 end

 private

 attr_reader :children
end
```

then in your tests you could do something similar to the following:

```
describe "#apply" do
  it "returns true" do
    children = [instance_double('SubClassA', my_method: true)]
    expect(children.first).to receive(:my_method)
    app = App.new(children: children)
    expect(app.apply).to be true
  end
end
```

using `expect_any_instance_of` can be a possible indication of a code smell, whenever I start thinking to use it I pause and look at my code and verify if I could write it in a better way so that it is easy  to test and dependency injection make the code easy to test.

here what you are trying to do is to hook inside the apply method and verify what it does but it is not possible for our client code in the test to inspect what is going on inside it. so I would make my dependencies injected and set my expectations on them whenever it is valid and reasonable to me to do so.

Comment: Hi Abdullah, thank you for such a detailed answer. My current solution is similar to yours. I also iterate over children in tests.
I hoped there would be even cleaner solution.

Comment: @AlexeySchepin you do not need hear to sect expectations on every sub class setting an expectation on just one of them is enough. so an array of one subclass instance in your test `[ instance_double('SubClassA', my_method: true) ]` will be enough to prove the case for all other sub classes since the `my_method` method is shated between them all in the parent class, which means failing to call this method on one sub-class will also fail for the rest of them.